# How to toggle Maximize/Minimize using jquery & animate.css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have two columns and a button centered between them, I tried to make the button toggle (maximize/Minimize) the two columns with jquery and animate.css.

It seems easy to make, but didn't work well, I can only make it minimized for once, all I want is to make like a toggle.
here is an example:

HTML:

```
    <a class="btn btn-default"> Maximize/Minimize <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<div class="col-xs-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius ducimus unde quasi dolorum necessitatibus voluptates perferendis consequuntur alias inventore quisquam distinctio sunt tempora quam doloremque, molestias praesentium voluptatem, sed optio.</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus necessitatibus excepturi ut dolorum placeat ducimus accusamus corrupti dicta mollitia enim dolore impedit pariatur, nobis dignissimos ad, magni distinctio voluptate assumenda.</div>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
  position: relative;
}
.btn{
  display:block;
}


  @keyframes slideOutDown {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);  // distance of the animation
  };
  
    @keyframes slideOutUp {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -200px, 0);  // distance of the animation
  }
```

JS:

```
   $(".btn").click(function(){
  $(".col-xs-6 , .btn").addClass('animated slideOutDown');
  $(".btn i").removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
  $(".btn i").addClass('fa-chevron-down');
    });
```

---

[Here is jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ExillustX/xwqasu92/1/)

I want to be able to maximize again with **`slideOutUp`** animation, after I minimize it.

Your helps are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `toggleClass()` here. currently, you are adding or removing some classes on a click, in the next click you will have to do reverse of that, you can define a if else condition to check which ones to do when, or you can simply just use `toggleClass()`

```
 $(".btn").click(function(){
      $(".col-xs-6 , .btn").toggleClass('animated slideOutDown');
      $(".btn i").toggleClass('fa-chevron-up');
      $(".btn i").toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');

  });
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to maximize it with `slideOutUp` animation.

Comment: i don't get it clearly, isn't your current code maximizing it?

Comment: your code maximize the columns without animation, but i want them to maximize with `slideOutUp`, i don't think `toggleClass()` is the right function for this :/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".btn").click(function() {

    $(".col-xs-6 , .btn").toggleClass("animated slideOutDown");

    $(".btn i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");

    $(".col-xs-6 , .btn").addClass("animated slideInUp");

});
```